# How to use existing HTML element in React?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to reference existing HTML element in React?
I have a page where React used only for small part of components and I have "video" element that exists on page before React loads. Then I have a react component which have a couple of props that should affect video element.

What is the best/correct way to achieve this?
Currently, in render method of a component, I use `document.getElementById('video-' + this.props.videoId)` and then manipulating it.  I thought that I can somehow use "refs" to say to reuse the existing HTML element, but not sure how and didn't found useful information.

Thanks!

Comment: You can lookup HTML elements that are not part of React and mutate it. For the once that are, preferred way would be to update props/state of component instead of using `refs`.

Comment: I guess you would be looking at ReactDOM.render if you want to render these things from react, but to manipulate it, I don't think I would be doing it from a component render method (you don't know how often that might be called). `refs` won't help you here, as these are rather to keep a reference on elements you created yourself in your component

Comment: You can use JavaScript without React to manipulate HTML elements that exist outside of React. What is your reason to use React here?

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is, you have an app, probably built in some other stack and you are trying to use React inside that app. The page is loaded before and then the React component renders. As pointed out by Icepickel, `refs` are for the components that are created by you inside the React app. So, you can't use that here.

Normally, it is discouraged to directly access the elements in the DOM. But since you are using it on a part of it, so it is totally fine. But doing it in the `render()` method is not the right choice here.

Instead what you can do is, utilize the React lifecycle methods to control the video player in a better way. Normally when a component is mounted on the DOM. Following lifecycle methods are called in the following order:

1. `constructor`
2. `componentWillMount`
3. `render`
4. `componentDidMount`

So, what I will suggest is, inside the `constructor` set the state using `document.getElementById('video-' + this.props.videoId)`. [I am assuming the page laods before the react component].

```js
let el = document.getElementById('video-' + this.props.videoId);
this.state = {
  videoPlayer: el;
}
```

And then later when your component is mounted. Inside the `componentDidMount`, change whatever you want to change in the video player.

I have also created a small [Code Sandbox Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-herschel-hqxnd?fontsize=14) to elaborate on the lifecycle methods. This way, you will be able to write cleaner code and easily manage the state of the video player.